# Relation between the Normal to the tangent plane and Gradient vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to understand the relation (if it exists) between the Normal to the plane tangent to the function $z=f(x,y)$ at point $(a,b)$ and its gradient vector at the same point. Since the normal has direction ratio as $f_x(a,b)$, $f_y(a,b)$ and some coefficient of z (referring equation of tangent plane $\Delta z=f_x\Delta x + f_y\Delta y$). And also gradient vector have the same components x as $f_x$ and y as $f_y$. I think that there should be a relation. $$\\$$ Is the Gradient vector the projection of the normal vector onto the xy plane? Can the normal vector be derived if one knows the gradient vector?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right with the correct normal vector. All of the normal vectors are constant multiples of the gradient

$$\nabla F = (F_x, F_y, F_z)$$

where $F = k$ for some constant $k$ is the equation of our surface. If we assume that $F_z\neq 0$, then we can divide this vector by $-F_z$ and get a parallel, but still normal, vector

$$\left(- \frac{F_x}{F_z}, -\frac{F_y}{F_z}, -1\right) = (f_x, f_y, -1)$$

by denoting $z=f(x,y)$ and using the Implicit function theorem. The projection of this vector in the $xy$-plane will get you the gradient of $z$ w.r.t. the other two variables, so any normal vector will get you a vector parallel to the $2$D gradient when you project it onto the $xy$ plane.